# UIView.animate and CGRect don't work - Swift 4

Tags: swift, animation, cgrect

I'm making this app where when you press a button , the character goes up and after that it's gonna go down.(I want it to act like this : When it's pressed , it has to go up 200y , then it starts going down)
This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var TheCharacter: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var TheRocket: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func TheCharacterJumps(_ sender: Any) {

        let TheCharacterY = self.TheCharacter.frame.origin.y
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {
            self.TheCharacter.frame = CGRect(x: 167, y: TheCharacterY - 194, width: 40, height: 40)
        }) { (finished) in

        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
            self.TheCharacter.frame = CGRect(x: 167, y: TheCharacterY + 435, width: 40, height: 40)
        }) { (finished) in

        }
    }
}
```

So it's like this : 
When the button is pressed , the character goes up and then it starts to fall.
But when the button is pressed two or more times in a row , instead of going up for like 200y , it goes up for only like 50y.
How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Do you want to disable the button during the animation? Is that the issue? Or is the issue with the animation? When you say the button is pressed twice in a row, do you mean in rapid succession?

Comment: No , I actually want the button to work like flappy bird an by "in a row" I mean it hasn't finished it's movement and it's pressed again.

Comment: Unfortunately (maybe fortunately), I have no idea what flappy bird is. So you want the user to be able to hit the button during the animation, reseting the animation, right?

Comment: Yes , I want the user to be able to hit the button during the animation, reseting the animation.Flappy bird : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQoJZuBwrkU

Comment: @rmaddy because they're different

Comment: Maybe this can [help](http://sweettutos.com/2017/03/09/build-your-own-flappy-bird-game-with-swift-3-and-spritekit/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a "flappy" animation you should use dynamic animators and add gravity to the scene and force to elements. Then UIKit will calculate animations.

Apple doc is: [UIDynamicAnimator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidynamicanimator).

In this case, every time you press button/screen add some upward force to the view and it will go up at its own and start going down after losing speed.

Look at Ray Wenderlich tutorial: [click](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76147/uikit-dynamics-tutorial-swift)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to implement a game out of this usage, maybe it's better to take a look at [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit) instead of UIKit. Take a look at [SKSpriteNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode) and how to add SKPhysicsBody.